# Is there any jurisdiction that recognizes after the fact consent?

Tags: united-states

After the fact consent means when someone "consents" to an act after it has occurred to them. is this recognised anywhere ?

Comment: I can't comment on it but yes it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Consent to what?

In [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), the use of the military requires the consent of the parliament, but in certain situations the government may act first and ask for permission later. Most recently, that was done for a [non-combatant evacuation operation from Sudan](https://www.dw.com/en/sudan-updates-germany-retroactively-approves-evacuations/a-65435841).

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

Anyone whose rights have been violated but accepts the status-quo rather than taking action has given de facto consent.

For example, if you steal my bike and I take no action to seek redress or to involve the relevant authorities, then I have de facto consented to the theft of my bike.